# Do we have to explicitly use RDDs and operations like foreach, parallelize to perform parallel processing in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, parallel-processing

If we use normal python operations for group by, merge, summing two dataframes versus explicitly using map, reducebykey, groupbykey etc, are there performance differences?

Is the former (normal operations) simple sequential processing while the latter parallel?

Does this mean for activting parallel processing we have to explicity use RDDs? normal dataframe usage is not parallel processing (despite done in pyspark)?

Comment: Please include a [MRE] or clarify what you are comparing. `pyspark`'s [dataframe api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html) works the same on distributed partitions just like the [rdd api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds). There are cases in which one is more efficient than the other.

Comment: groupby vs groupbykey ; merge vs joinbykey

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have to explicitly use RDDs ... to perform parallel processing in pyspark?

No. Spark APIs are distributed as well.

*"Will there be a difference in performance of Dataframes vs RDDs for specific situations?"* E.g. `df1.join(df2)` vs `df1.rdd.union(df2.rdd)`

Yes.

I at least can't quote a source that says one is more performant in all situations with compelling proof. E.g. [this](https://www.adsquare.com/comparing-performance-of-spark-dataframes-api-to-spark-rdd/).

But by and large, word of mouth is Spark is faster.